# take to the location of file instead opening or saving it in content query webpart

Tags: content-query-web-part

Hi i need to get the location of the documents in content query web-part where I have modified the xslt to get the column for documents to display from different sub-sites.
I am trying o pull all the checked out items by the user and showing. I have succeeded in doing so by modifying xslt. But when I click on the document or item it is asking me to save or open. I need a column in content query web-part which would take me to the location of document.what property do i need to add to get the location of the corresponding items in CQWP SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ContentByQueryWebPart.UseCopyUtil Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.usecopyutil%28v=office.12%29.aspx)  sets or sets whether the URL for items should use the View Property page.

Set it to `True` in order to render the Item Url as View page Url:

```
<WebUrl>/_layouts/15/CopyUtil.aspx?Use=id&Action=dispform&ItemId=<ItemId>&ListId=<ListId>&WebId=<WebId>&SiteId=<SiteId>
```

### How to update ContentByQueryWebPart.UseCopyUtil property

- Export CQWP
- Open web part file and locate `UseCopyUtil` element, update its value
  to `True`
- Save changes and upload web part file, then add web part on the page

Comment: I am not using any object model just modifying the xslt. What property change needs to be done.

Comment: I've already pointed in the answer what property should be changed, anyway the answer has been updated to reflect how to apply the changes

Comment: I have got it but i only get the title of the item as blank for all the items even though they are pointing to the exact location . How to get the title of the item instead of blank.